# Solving $y = \frac{x}{1-x} $ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How can I solve this equation for $x$?
> $$
> y = \frac{x}{1-x}
> $$

I feel like this should be an obvious and easy answer, but I cannot come up with the right search terms to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the first thing to do is get rid of the denominator.  Multiply both sides by $(1 - x)$.  This will get you to:

$$ y(1 - x) = x $$

If you then multiply it through it becomes:

$$ y - yx = x $$

Now, we can gather the $x$ terms together onto one side:

$$y = x + yx$$

Now that all the $x$ terms are together, since they are all to the same power (the first power), we can factor them out:

$$y = x(1 + y) $$

Now, to get $x$ by itself, you can just divide by $(1 + y)$, which yields:

$$x = \frac{y}{1 + y} $$

Answer (score 2):

For this one, it's easiest to begin by taking the reciprocal of both sides. Then you'll see that

$$\frac 1 y = \frac{1-x}{x} = \frac 1 x - 1$$

You can solve for $x$ from here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean **componendo et dividendo**?

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
  \text{alterando} &
  \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d} \\
  \text{invertendo} &
  \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{b}{a}=\frac{d}{c} \\
  \text{componendo} &
  \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a+b}{b}=\frac{c+d}{d} \\
  \text{dividendo} &
  \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a-b}{b}=\frac{c-d}{d} \\
  \text{componendo et dividendo} &
  \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d} \\ \hline
\end{array}

Now

$$
\frac{\color{red}{x}}{\color{blue}{1-x}}=
\frac{\color{red}{y}}{\color{blue}{1}} \implies
\frac{\color{red}{x}}{\color{blue}{1-x}+\color{red}{x}}=
\frac{\color{red}{y}}{\color{blue}{1}+\color{red}{y}} \implies
x=\frac{y}{1+y}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ y = \frac{x}{1-x} $$

$$ (1-x)y = x $$

$$ y-xy = x $$

$$ y=xy+x$$

Factor out the $x \cdots$